# Walking Animation

Tags: java, loops, animation, bufferedimage

So I have been looking at Notch's Metagun source code and I can't seem to figure out how he got to get the sprites animating. Right now all I am trying to do is loop through some of images of a character's walking animation. Here is the code, my output,so far,only shows the first image of walking which is the character standing still:
package animation;

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class SpriteAnimation extends JComponent{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    int frame=0;
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        try{
        BufferedImage still = ImageIO.read(SpriteAnimation.class.getResource("still.png"));
        BufferedImage walkRight = ImageIO.read(SpriteAnimation.class.getResource("right.png"));
        BufferedImage midWalk = ImageIO.read(SpriteAnimation.class.getResource("mid.png"));
        BufferedImage walkLeft = ImageIO.read(SpriteAnimation.class.getResource("left.png"));
        BufferedImage[] states={still,walkRight,midWalk};       
        int frame=0;
        do{
            frame++;
            if(frame>=3){
                frame=0;
                g.drawImage(states[frame],0,0,null);
            }
        }
        while(true);
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: First things first: there shouldn't be a loop there. `paint` is called each time the component must be redrawed, but your code tries to act as the main loop of the animation, when it actually should just draw *one frame*. The animation loop should be controlled by some kind of `Timer` that ask the window to redraw itself every X milliseconds, and your `paint` method should draw the current frame of your animation.

Comment: 1) Change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..` 2) `while(true);`  never do that in a GUI!

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) For custom painting in a `JComponent`, override `paintComponent(Graphics)` instead of `paint(Graphics)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why the other guys went ahead and just tried to refactor your code without even mentioning the real issue here: if you're using `Swing` to make your animation, that loop there is a big **no no**. You're basically hogging the `EDT` and stalling the whole GUI by doing that.

You should rewrite your code so your `SpriteAnimation` draws only *one frame* each time the `paint` method is called, while the animation loop is managed externaly by some kind of timer.

Quick example:

```
public class SpriteAnimation extends JComponent{
    private int currentFrame = 0;
    private BufferedImage[] frames;

    public SpriteAnimation(){
        /**
         * Load your frames
         */
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        currentFrame++;
        if(frame >= 3)
            frame = 0;

        // we pass this as the ImageObserver in case the images are 
        // loaded asynchronously
        g.drawImage(frames[currentFrame], 0, 0, this);                
    }
}
```

And in your main method:

```
// Timer is a swing timer
Timer timer = new Timer(
    100, 
    new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            // main frame is your main animation canvas (eg a JFrame)
            mainFrame.repaint();
        }
    });
timer.start();
```

- [Swing Timer Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
if(frame>=3){
    frame=0;
    g.drawImage(states[frame],0,0,null);
}
```

needs to be:

```
if(frame>=3){
    frame=0;
}
g.drawImage(states[frame],0,0,null);
```

additionally, your `states` array is missing `walkLeft`:

```
BufferedImage[] states={still,walkRight,midWalk};
```

which also means that you probably want your condition to be `frame > states.length` on the above snippet.

NOTE: You should really go about using timers as suggested by @asermax's comment, but this should fix the bugs you had at least.